# Libgdx MoveToAction - Can't get it to work

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

I'm trying to use MoveToAction to update an onscreen actor.  However, it doesn't seem to be doing anything and I can't find many online examples to help (those that I have found suggest I'm setting it up correctly, though obviously I'm not).  I update positionX via a setPositionX method, and have been able to determine through logging that positionX is updating.  Is there something else I need to add to make this work?

```
public MyActor(boolean playerIsEast, int positionX) {
        setBounds(this.getX(), 140, 50, 200);
        this.positionX = positionX;
        this.setX(400);
        currentImage = AssetLoader.losEast;
        moveAction = new MoveToAction();
        moveAction.setDuration(1);
        this.addAction(moveAction);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float alpha) {
        batch.draw(currentImage, this.getX(), 140, 50, 200);
    }

    @Override
    public void act(float delta) {
        moveAction.setPosition(positionX, 140);
        for (Iterator<Action> iter = this.getActions().iterator(); iter
                .hasNext();) {
            iter.next().act(delta);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create the action, that is where you set the target position, not in the act method. And there is no need for your `act` method to handle the action, because that's already built into the Actor superclass.

So it should look like this:

```
public MyActor(boolean playerIsEast, int positionX) {
    setBounds(this.getX(), 140, 50, 200);
    this.positionX = positionX;
    this.setX(400);
    currentImage = AssetLoader.losEast;
    moveAction = new MoveToAction();
    moveAction.setDuration(1);
    moveAction.setPosition(positionX, 140);
    this.addAction(moveAction);
}

@Override
public void draw(Batch batch, float alpha) {
    batch.draw(currentImage, this.getX(), 140, 50, 200);
}

@Override
public void act(float delta) {
    super.act(delta); //This handles actions for you and removes them when they finish

    //You could do stuff other than handle actions here, such as 
    //changing a sprite for an animation.
}
```

However, it is a good idea to use pooled actions to avoid triggering the GC. The Actions class provides convenience methods for this. So you could simplify this further:

```
public MyActor(boolean playerIsEast, int positionX) {
    setBounds(this.getX(), 140, 50, 200);
    this.positionX = positionX;
    this.setX(400);
    currentImage = AssetLoader.losEast;
    this.addAction(Actions.moveTo(positionX, 140, 1)); //last argument is duration
}
```